# not getting updatedBy field from table using JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table entity_detail that has following structure:

```
id  detail_id  center_code  Comments  updated_by  updated_on   created_on   created_by
1    121       0            Test      user        2020-04-22   2020-04-21   user
2    122       1            Test      user1       2020-04-22   2020-04-22   user
```

I have an entity corresponding to this table:

```
    @Entity(name = "entity_detail")
    public class EntityDetail extends AuditableEntity {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;

      private Long detailId;

      private Boolean centerCode;

      private String comments;
 }
```

There is another class AuditableEntity which manages the Audit.

```
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    @Data
    public class AuditableEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdOn;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String updatedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedOn;

}
```

Now when I try to fetch the data from the table by using id:

```
savedEntityDetailTest = entityDetailRepository.findById(id);
```

All the attributes which are coming from AuditableEntity get returned null.

which means when I try to fetch updatedBy field using the following line it returns null.

```
savedEntityDetailTest.getUpdatedBy();
```

while when I try to get comments in the same way I get value which is saved in the table.

```
savedEntityDetailTest.getcomments();
```

Please suggest me a fixture or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Add `EnableJpaAuditing` annotation above your `main` class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class H2Database2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(H2Database2Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Add `MappedSuperclass` annotation to the `AuditableEntity` class.

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public class AuditableEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdOn;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String updatedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedOn;

}
```

Add `Data` annotation to the `EntityDetail` class.

```
@Entity(name = "entity_detail")
@Data
public class EntityDetail extends AuditableEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Long detailId;

    private Boolean centerCode;

    private String comments;
}
```

And Add `AuditorAware` like below:

```
@Component
public class SecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        return Optional.of(((User)authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
    }
}
```

Comment: That has already been added this woks with other entities but for this one.

Comment: And the required resultset comes when I fetch the data using nativeQuery

Comment: @ShubhamParmar: I add a sample in https://github.com/NasirSepehri/hibernate-inheritance-mapping .